# Horizontal alignment on row PdfPRow itextsharp (c#)

Tags: c#, itext, pdfptable

Need some help here. I'm trying text within a row looks in the same horizontal line as it's corresponding dotted lines
This is the result

[image]

And this is the part of my code related to the image:

```
        Font coverHeaderFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 18, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK);
        Font tableContentFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 16, Font.BOLDITALIC, BaseColor.BLACK);
        Font textIndexFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 11, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK);
        Font invisibleFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 11, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.WHITE);
        Font underText = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 10, Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, BaseColor.BLACK);

        //table creation
        PdfPTable tblCon = new PdfPTable(3); //3 columns
        tblCon.WidthPercentage = 90f; //wide %
        tblCon.HorizontalAlignment = 1; //centered
        //tblCon.LockedWidth = true;

        //relative col widths in proportions - 1/3 and 2/3
        float[] widths = new float[] { 4f, 6f, 2f };//{ 6f, 4f, 2f };
        tblCon.SetWidths(widths);

        //leave a gap before and after the table
        tblCon.SpacingBefore = 20f;
        tblCon.SpacingAfter = 30f; 

        //Header Cell
        string appHeader = "Applications";
        Chunk cAppHeader = new Chunk(appHeader, underText);

        // CELLS
        PdfPCell cellName = new PdfPCell();
        cellName.PaddingTop = 10f;
        cellName.VerticalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_TOP;
        cellName.BorderWidth = 1;
        cellName.MinimumHeight = 30f;
        //cellName.HorizontalAlignment = 0; //0=Left, 1=Center, 2=Right

        PdfPCell cellSeparator = new PdfPCell();
        cellSeparator.PaddingTop = 10f;
        cellSeparator.VerticalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_TOP;
        cellSeparator.BorderWidth = 1;
        cellSeparator.MinimumHeight = 20f;

        PdfPCell cellPage = new PdfPCell();
        cellPage.PaddingTop = 10f;
        cellPage.VerticalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_TOP;
        cellPage.BorderWidth = 1;
        cellPage.MinimumHeight = 30f;

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfDetailsPDF.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0) //first column, just header
            {
                cellName.AddElement(new Paragraph(cAppHeader));
                cellSeparator.AddElement(new Paragraph(".", invisibleFont)); 
                cellPage.AddElement(new Paragraph("1", invisibleFont));
            }

            var obj = listOfDetailsPDF[i];
            String title = (string)obj.GetType().GetProperty("applicantName").GetValue(obj, null);
            Chunk cTitle = new Chunk(title, textIndexFont);

            int pNPage = (int)obj.GetType().GetProperty("pdfPages").GetValue(obj, null);
            String numberPage = pNPage.ToString();
            Chunk cNumPage = new Chunk(numberPage, textIndexFont);

            cellName.AddElement(new Paragraph(cTitle));
            cellSeparator.AddElement(new Paragraph(dottedLine));
            cellPage.AddElement(new Paragraph(cNumPage));

        }
        tblCon.Rows.Add(new PdfPRow(new PdfPCell[] { cellName, cellSeparator, cellPage }));
```

I just want: the name with the dotted line with the number page look in the same line in every row.
Thank you

Comment: I already tested with the same MinimumHeight in every cell, and still resulting the same image

Comment: You say *I'm trying text within a row looks with the same horizontal alignment* but you also say that you're *not talking about left, center or right alignment.* I only know one other type of horizontal alignment, and that's justified alignment. What type of horizontal alignment are you talking about? And could you correct the grammatical errors when you update your question with this extra information? Maybe I'm misunderstanding *I'm trying text within a row looks with the same horizontal alignment .* (That sentence doesn't really make sense.)

Comment: Also: (1.) why are you still using iText 5 instead of iText 7? iText 5 is no longer supported. (2.) Why are you using a table to create this type of TOC. All the official examples just use a `DottedLineSeparator` without a table.

Comment: Sorry for my english, maybe I have to explain better. Number pages are not at the same horizontal line as its corresponding DottedLines... That's what I tried to explain

Comment: And regarding your questions: (1) I'm using ItextSharp 5 because that's the version it's showed in my Manage NuGet Package (Visual Studio 2013) and (2) With the TOC there are method that has assemblies that are not in my version, so I used Pdf Table instead.

Comment: You are trusting your incorrect configuration of Visual Studio more thsn the original author of iText. Let's check the Nuget site: https://www.nuget.org/packages/itext7/ Oops, that's not version 5, is it? iText 5 is no longer supported. The recent releases are *maintenance* releases that are made for paying users. Please use iText 7 instead of 5.

Comment: Once you've upgraded to iText 7, you'll be able to use the dotted line separator as explained in the tutorial: https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-3